# Access to XMLHttpRequest at

Tags: angularjs

angular.js:12845 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/my%20stdeis/loction%20sec%20page.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using a supported protocol. As the error reads, only http, data, chrome, chrome-extension and https are supported. You however are trying to use "file".

I believe you can find the solution to your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10752078/10743628).